# How to use a dynamic Bearer token in restful technical profile in ADB2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an API that I could access using a bearer token that has a TTL of 1 hour. I need to consume this API through ADB2C.

As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile), the bearer token is read from a policy Key B2C_1A_B2cRestClientAccessToken:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
  <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return loyaltyNumber claim</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-app-name.azurewebsites.NET/api/identity/signup</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2cRestClientAccessToken" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

However, the policy key (B2C_1A_B2cRestClientAccessToken) is static whereas in my case, the bearer token needs to be retrieved everytime the API needs to be consumed by ADB2C. How do I accomplish this?